# how to run python script in ansible playbook using virtual enviroment?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, ansible

I'm trying run python script test.py using a virtual environment.
in standard Linux bash it simply looks like

```
source venv/bin/activate
screen -dm  python3 test.py
```

But how I can do the same using ansible-playbook?

Answer (score 3):

When you create a virtual environment in python, a 'python3' interpreter is added in the 'bin' folder of the virtual environment (venv/bin/python3).
This interpreter has all the dependencies/packages that you've installed using pip for the project.

So, if you want to execute a script using this interpreter, you can provide the complete path to the interpreter.

Example:
Consider the python file: test.py
Name of virtual environment: venv
Command to execute the script:  venv/bin/python3 test.py